# How to use if else in react.js.coffee

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, coffeescript

js.coffee for my views and quite not sure how to use if else in it tried some stuff but couldn't get it! new to react.

```
        #Payment Form
    React.DOM.div
      className: "row"
      React.DOM.div
        className: "sixteen wide column"
        React.DOM.div
          id: "dropin"
    React.DOM.div
      # Payment method Selection
      React.createElement Jobs.PaymentMethodSelect,
        payments: @props.payments
        paymet_method: @props.job.transaction_token
        saveJobValues: @props.saveJobValues
```

this is my code for a drop down! passing payments props everythin is working fine!

but i want to hide is the @props.payment.count > 0. when user dont have payment method it hides the form!

i tried adding " if @props.payment.count > 0 " but the dropdown hides for ever even if the user have payment method!

Comment: Sure you're not confusing `.count` and `.length`?

Comment: What type of object is `@props.payment` ?